# How to decrease vertex and Face ?

Tags: modeling, vertices, faces

Everyone . This is my private work. I'm trying to upload this model via SketchFab.com bbut this model got too much data and too much Face 
Anything i can do to reduce face and vertex ??
[image]

Comment: Have you tried the Decimate Modifier?

Comment: Do any objects have a subsurf modifier that can be reduced or removed? For instance, small detail items with 2 or more levels that may only need one or none.

Comment: Decreasing subdivsions and removing inner faces is definitely the best way

Comment: There was a day when I thought anything over a million vertices was a lot :) Time flies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say the best thing you could do would be to decrease the amount of subdivisions on faces which are less likely to be seen, So for instance the chain, yes they play a valuable role in telling the story of the tank but when a texture is added you don't need as many faces.

So just think of spaces that people wont be able to see. Like the back part and the inside or even underneath it. But great bloody Model mate, I can see you like Battlefield 1.

Also for the pins/bolts/rivets along the tank, are they spheres? If so change them to Hemisphere's.

Comment: Great advice , Thx you man . and by the way ,this model has been built before battlefield 1 release but i still looking forward to build some model base on battlefield 1 :)

Comment: No worries mate.